# What is the plumbing diagram symbol for a water hammer arrestor?

Tags: plumbing, planning

Despite my best Google queries, I simply cannot find an image of a typical water hammer arrestor symbol for a top-down 2D plumbing drawing of a single floor. Can any provide an image of this symbol or tell me if one does not exist? I certainly could create my own symbol and explain it in the key (I plan to provide a key anyways), but I would like to use standard symbols wherever possible.

I am also planning to do a riser diagram separate from the top-down 2D drawing.

Comment: [The website for the industry journal Hydraulics](http://hydraulicspneumatics.com/) & Pneumatics has a [page](http://hydraulicspneumatics.com/other-technologies/chapter-16-accumulators) on accumulators with a number of interesting symbols for "accumulators." There are also more symbols [here](http://hydraulicspneumatics.com/other-technologies/book-2-chapter-1-hydraulic-accumulators-part-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this nifty little symbol:

[image]